# How to specify remote JKS keystore with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore, jks

In Tomcat you configure your `server.xml` with the following SSL `Connector`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    proxyPort=""
    keystoreFile="/etc/path/to/keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="12345"
    keystoreType="jks"
    truststorePass="12345"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

...or somethign similar. But `keyStoreFile` doesn't seem to allow anything other than local file paths. What if I wanted to store my JKS on a remote server? It would be nice to be able to specify something like:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    proxyPort=""
    keystoreFile="http://mycert01.example.org/myapp/keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="12345"
    keystoreType="jks"
    truststorePass="12345"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Obviously this would present security issues, but if `mycert01.example.org` was behind a VPN, I don't think it would be any more or less secure than something on the local file system.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what would I have to do to make it possible?

Comment: Why? The keystore contains a private key. The very last thing you would want to do with it is put it on an HTTP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible with the available `Connector`. You would have to rewrite the `Connector` to make this possible. Otherwise, you might be able to work around this if you map the remote filesystem (by mounting it, I guess, but this is just a guess). I've never tried doing that for this kind of scenario and I don't recommend it. Hosting your SSL keystore remotely is quite simply the wrong way to do things - both for security and efficiency.